# Minion Pro and IPA

Tags: arabic, minionpro

I'm using MinionPro with `fontspec` on Windows 10. Some IPA symbols do not show up when I compile with XeLaTeX.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tipa}  
 \usepackage{fontspec} 
 \setmainfont{Minion Pro} 

    \begin{document}

    \textipa{Q}ala   

    \textipa{P}ila 

    \end{document}
```

[image]

The box appears with some sounds: `\textipa{P}`, `\textipa{Q}`, and `\textgamma`.

Comment: Also please tell us which engine and format do you use.

Comment: The Minion Pro font lacks U+0294 and U+0295, so it's not surprising they don't show up.

Comment: This compiles with no problem for me (with a font substitution of course).